# Error trying to use blur with Haarcascades

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, haar-classifier

I'm trying to do a project on my own and I thought I could make this work, but that problem happened and well... I don't know what is going on. The objective of this project is to blur eyes on photos or even videos.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

people = cv2.imread('Computer-Vision-with-Python/DATA/people.jpg',0)
people2 = cv2.imread('Computer-Vision-with-Python/DATA/people2.jpg')

def display(img, cmap='gray'):
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.imshow(img,cmap='gray')

eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Computer-Vision-with-Python/DATA/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml')

def detect_eye(img):
    face_img = img.copy()

    face_rects = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(face_img,scaleFactor=1.2,minNeighbors=6)

    for (x,y,w,h) in face_rects:
        cv2.rectangle(face_img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,255),10)

    return face_img

def detect_and_blur_eye(img):

    eye_img = img.copy()
    roi = img.copy()

    eye_rects = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(eye_img,scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=6) 

    for (x,y,w,h) in eye_rects: 
        print (x,y,w,h)
        roi = roi[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        blurred_roi = cv2.medianBlur(roi,7)

        eye_img[y:y+h,x:x+w] = blurred_roi

    return eye_img

results = detect_and_blur_eye(people)
```

After that, I get this error:

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-259-f561e117d7f8> in <module>
----> 1 results = detect_and_blur_eye(people)

<ipython-input-258-2ab32e080f88> in detect_and_blur_eye(img)
     12         blurred_roi = cv2.medianBlur(roi,7)
     13 
---> 14         eye_img[y:y+h,x:x+w] = blurred_roi
     15 
     16     return eye_img

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

---

I don't know what is going on! Please guide me in this situation. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I was able to discover something that can led me to solve the problem. I changed the function so I could get some values.

```
def detect_and_blur_eye(img):

    eye_img = img.copy()
    roi = img.copy()

    eye_rects = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(eye_img,scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=6) 

    for (x,y,w,h) in eye_rects: 
        print (type(eye_rects))
        print (x,y,w,h)
        roi = roi[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        print(roi.shape)
        #blurred_roi = cv2.medianBlur(roi,7)

        #eye_img[y:y+h,x:x+w] = blurred_roi

    return eye_img

results = detect_and_blur_eye(people)
```

And it gives me back this:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
1182 414 45 45
(45, 45)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
595 427 56 56
(0, 0)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
512 430 57 57
(0, 0)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
270 470 60 60
(0, 0)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
349 475 56 56
(0, 0)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
981 375 62 62
(0, 0)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
842 389 50 50
(0, 0)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
762 391 50 50
(0, 0)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
1072 390 54 54
(0, 0)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
1238 399 48 48
(0, 0)
```

So, for some reason my shape is (0,0)

Comment: Nice project! What happens if you print(x,y,w,h) - perhaps no face is found (in some frames), so eye_rects is None, so x,y,w,h (which need to be integers for the roi slice) are of the wrong type. So you possibly/probably just need to handle these exception cases.

Comment: Are you able to post your two sample images?

Comment: These are the images: 
https://p2prh.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/p2p-talents.jpg 
and
https://rollingstone.uol.com.br/media/_versions/turmadamonicacirco_widelg.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your problem like @jtlz2 said is due to eyes not being found in the images and hence having none type which when you try to assign it it raises an error. There can be two workarounds of this that either you use a better classifier which fill find eyes but then if you want to use it for videos you will want real time and can't use CNNs. An alternative can be dlib facial key points. Other than this if you want to continue with haar-cascades only then you can do this:

```
try:
    print (x,y,w,h)
    roi = roi[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    blurred_roi = cv2.medianBlur(roi,7)

    eye_img[y:y+h,x:x+w] = blurred_roi
except:
    pass
```

This way if any errors are there then your eyes won't be blurred but the program will not throw an error.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get what you were trying to say.

Comment: I've just edited the post with some good information, maybe it can help! Thanks for your time

Comment: You shouldn't really use a bare except statement - perhaps at least print a warning? :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to discover the problem. In the function, I need to reset ROI before having another value and I was not doing that.

```
def detect_and_blur_eye(img):

    eye_img = img.copy()
    roi = img.copy()

    eye_rects = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(eye_img,scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=6,minSize=(5,5)) 

    for (x,y,w,h) in eye_rects:
        roi = img.copy()
        print (type(eye_rects))
        print (x,y,w,h)
        roi = roi[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        print(roi.shape)
        blurred_roi = cv2.medianBlur(roi,21)
        eye_img[y:y+h,x:x+w] = blurred_roi

    return eye_img
```

That Works!

Comment: What if there are no eyes in the image (frame) - what happens then? This case is bound to occur when you start applying this to video

Comment: Why not just do `roi = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]` ? You can also pass `img` directly into the detector rather than making a copy every time